# Windows installed from another windows creates a dependency

Tags: windows-7, boot

I recently bought an SSD and wanted to install windows on it.

As my motherboard refuses to boot USB stick and DVD reader is broken, I installed Windows 7 with a mounted iso of the MSDNAA version I have, and installed it on the ssd.

It installed great, but it now seems that the Windows on the SSD depends on the windows from which it was installed : if I unplug the HDD, the computer won't boot from SSD (BOOT FAILURE), and windows prevents me to erase the windows installation on the HDD.

But I can boot from the SSD if the HDD is present...

Is this dependency normal, and is there a way to make the windows install on the SSD standalone?

WHAT I DID THAT WORKED :
I used Visual BCD Editor, and tried restoration, changing the boot manager drive, etc.. but it only worked when I set the SSD partition as 'active' in drive management (was not the case by default).

Comment: You should figure why you can't boot to a USB stick that seems strange

Comment: @Ramhound I wish I could! But I tried every single combination in the BIOS/software that prepares the key/iso image (tried that with linux also), none works.

Comment: Ask that question we can help you figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem quite likely has nothing to do with your installed windows images, but with the location of the windows boot partition. If it's on the hdd the you won't be able to boot if it's disconnected. try cloning the bootrecord using bcdedit to your new HD.

you can find info on how to do this [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1d56cfa4-477f-4065-9675-b2f376e81bcc/using-bcdedit-to-change-boot-partitions)

Comment: Could you give sources as to how the OP should proceed with bcdedit? Otherwise this would better fit a comment.